# CSS background property not working on Safari 5.7.1

Tags: css, safari

```css
background: #27AE61 url("../images/banner.png") no-repeat scroll center center / cover;
```

The above CSS is working properly in firefox, google chrome and internet explorer but not on safari 5.7.1. Why ? What is the solution?

Comment: Why is there a backslash in that shorthand?

Comment: i found the answer the problem was safari doesn't support background-size instead i have to use  -webkit-background-size : cover; then it worked thanks for reply..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try writing your css in long manner instead of shorthand way, like this:

`background-color: #27AE61;
    background-image: url("../images/banner.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
    background-size: cover;`

It looks the said version of **Safari** does not support shorthand css for background.